# postgres constraint based on SELECT condition

Tags: postgresql, constraints

ᕼello! I think I have a somewhat tricky postgres situation:

`parent`s have `child`ren. `child`ren have an `age`, and a flag that they are the `appreciated`.

**The rule:** a parent can't appreciate two children of the same age!

My question is: *how to enforce this rule*?

Current schema:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent INTEGER REFERENCES parent(id) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  age INTEGER NOT NULL,
  appreciated BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
```

Put some values in:

```
INSERT INTO parent(name) VALUES
  ('bob'),    -- assume bob's id = 0
  ('mary');   -- assume mary's id = 1

INSERT INTO child(parent, name, age, appreciated) VALUES
  (0, 'child1', 10, FALSE), -- Bob has children 1, 2, 3
  (0, 'child2', 10, FALSE),
  (0, 'child3', 15, FALSE),
  (1, 'child4', 20, FALSE), -- Mary has children 4, 5, 6
  (1, 'child5', 20, FALSE),
  (1, 'child6', 10, FALSE);
```

All fine so far. No child is appreciated, which is always valid.

Mary is allowed to appreciate child6:

```
UPDATE child SET appreciated=TRUE WHERE name='child6';
```

Bob is allowed to appreciate child2. child2 is the same age as child6 (who is already appreciated), but child6 is not Bob's child.

```
UPDATE child SET appreciated=TRUE WHERE name='child2';
```

Bob now *cannot* appreciate child1. This child1 is the same age as child2, and child2 is already appreciated.

```
UPDATE child SET appreciated=TRUE WHERE name='child2'; -- This needs to FAIL!
```

How do I enforce such a constraint? I'm open to all kinds of solutions, but modifying the general schema is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to limit upserts to only be accomplished by a procedure that you define?

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a `UNIQUE` partial index, like so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON child(parent,age) WHERE appreciated;
```

So every pair of `parent`,`age` has to be unique, but only when appreciated children are considered.

Comment: Holy moly postgres is insane and this is exactly the answer I was looking for!

Comment: I have a quick followup question: can I achieve this with `ALTER TABLE` syntax?

Comment: No. If it wasn't for the `WHERE` part it would have been possible, but being a partial index, it has to be created with `CREATE INDEX`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a trigger that activates BEFORE the insert/update and that fails if the constraint you create is not satisfied.
I suppose it should be like

```
create trigger <trigger_name>
before insert or update on <table_name>
for each row
declare
dummy number;
begin
select count(*)
into dummy
from <table_name>
where (appreciated=TRUE and :new.child = child and :new.age = age);

if dummy > 0 then
  raise_application_error(-20001,'Too many appreciated children');
end if;
end;
```

[Some documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: This sounds promising - but how do I see that multiple children of the same age are appreciated BEFORE both those children are appreciated? It sounds like I would have to have some notion of the future intent of an incoming SQL query... I'd really appreciate some more detailed example code!

Comment: in the <code> section you have access to the mutating table and to the row that is going to be inserted or updated :)

Comment: Ah that sounds like it could work! I'd really appreciate a more detailed answer, this only really shows me how to define a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I would think to do is add a flag grateful(?) == false to the parent model and when child.appreciated == true { parent.grateful == true }

Check the value of parent.grateful in the function that acts on child.appreciated. 
If parent.grateful == true
 return "sorry this parent has already shown their appreciation."
LOL this is an interesting concept though. Good Luck. :)

Comment: Unfortunately parents can appreciate many children! Just not two children of the same age.